# SQL Connection (Exception fail)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When trying to connect to sql through sqlconnection I get an error, "NullReferenceException was unhandled"
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DBLabControllers.dll

Additional information: Objektreferensen har inte angetts till en instans av ett objekt."

Why do I get exception fail and how do I fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DBLabs
{


    public class DBConnection : DBLabsDLL.DBConnectionBase
    {


        public DBConnection()
        {
            string connectionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            connectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=www3.idt.mdh.se;User ID=ezi15001;Password=********";

            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }


        public override bool login(string username, string password)
        {


            string constring = "Data Source = www3.idt.mdh.se;" + "Database=" + username + "_db;" + "User ID=" + username + ";" + "Password=" + password;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(constring);
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                myConnection.Close();
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            return true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are using  `string connectionString = null;` you are making connection to null

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your connection string to `NULL` before you call it in the button click method, you need to pass the connection string to it.